# Unknown error when playing game for a long time

Tags: android, libgdx, runtime-error

I m developing the LibGdx based game in android device. I am getting this unknown error when I played for long time.

### Logcat

```
02-20 19:38:01.581: D/dalvikvm(26926): dump native stack for : main
02-20 19:38:01.603: D/dalvikvm(26926): unwind backtrace
02-20 19:38:01.647: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native symbol
02-20 19:38:01.671: D/dalvikvm(26926): format backtrace line
02-20 19:38:01.671: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native done
02-20 19:38:01.699: D/dalvikvm(26926): dump native stack for : Binder_3
02-20 19:38:01.699: D/dalvikvm(26926): unwind backtrace
02-20 19:38:01.703: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native symbol
02-20 19:38:01.711: D/dalvikvm(26926): format backtrace line
02-20 19:38:01.711: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native done
02-20 19:38:01.712: D/dalvikvm(26926): dump native stack for : android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorThread
02-20 19:38:01.712: D/dalvikvm(26926): unwind backtrace
02-20 19:38:01.714: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native symbol
02-20 19:38:01.730: D/dalvikvm(26926): format backtrace line
02-20 19:38:01.731: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native done
02-20 19:38:01.775: D/dalvikvm(26926): dump native stack for : SoundPoolThread
02-20 19:38:01.775: D/dalvikvm(26926): unwind backtrace
02-20 19:38:01.781: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native symbol
02-20 19:38:01.790: D/dalvikvm(26926): format backtrace line
02-20 19:38:01.791: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native done
02-20 19:38:01.793: D/dalvikvm(26926): dump native stack for : SoundPool
02-20 19:38:01.794: D/dalvikvm(26926): unwind backtrace
02-20 19:38:01.796: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native symbol
02-20 19:38:01.797: D/dalvikvm(26926): format backtrace line
02-20 19:38:01.797: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native done
02-20 19:38:01.799: D/dalvikvm(26926): dump native stack for : GLThread 10998
02-20 19:38:01.799: D/dalvikvm(26926): unwind backtrace
02-20 19:38:01.802: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native symbol
02-20 19:38:01.804: D/dalvikvm(26926): format backtrace line
02-20 19:38:01.804: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native done
02-20 19:38:01.916: D/dalvikvm(26926): dump native stack for : Binder_2
02-20 19:38:01.916: D/dalvikvm(26926): unwind backtrace
02-20 19:38:01.917: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native symbol
02-20 19:38:01.917: D/dalvikvm(26926): format backtrace line
02-20 19:38:01.917: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native done
02-20 19:38:01.921: D/dalvikvm(26926): dump native stack for : Binder_1
02-20 19:38:01.921: D/dalvikvm(26926): unwind backtrace
02-20 19:38:01.922: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native symbol
02-20 19:38:01.923: D/dalvikvm(26926): format backtrace line
02-20 19:38:01.923: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native done
02-20 19:38:01.931: D/dalvikvm(26926): dump native stack for : Compiler
02-20 19:38:01.931: D/dalvikvm(26926): unwind backtrace
02-20 19:38:01.933: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native symbol
02-20 19:38:01.933: D/dalvikvm(26926): format backtrace line
02-20 19:38:01.933: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native done
02-20 19:38:01.934: D/dalvikvm(26926): dump native stack for : JDWP
02-20 19:38:01.934: D/dalvikvm(26926): unwind backtrace
02-20 19:38:01.938: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native symbol
02-20 19:38:01.938: D/dalvikvm(26926): format backtrace line
02-20 19:38:01.938: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native done
02-20 19:38:01.939: D/dalvikvm(26926): dump native stack for : GC
02-20 19:38:01.940: D/dalvikvm(26926): unwind backtrace
02-20 19:38:01.941: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native symbol
02-20 19:38:01.941: D/dalvikvm(26926): format backtrace line
02-20 19:38:01.941: D/dalvikvm(26926): get native done
02-20 19:38:01.943: D/dalvikvm(26926): Prepare stack traces for '/data/anr/traces.txt' done
02-20 19:38:01.944: I/dalvikvm(26926): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: post the content of /data/anr/traces.txt because the above is just the info that stack traces were generated, which is practically useless to narrow down the problem

Comment: I do not find data/anr/traces.txt in my tab

Comment: I don't know where the traces are stored but I suspect they're on the device's file system.